# Outlook appointment sent from msg file not in calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

I've made a draft appointment in Outlook and saved it as a msg file on my local workstation. A few days later, I've opened the msg file from Windows Explorer and sent out the invite.

On each response coming in, an information box says *"The meeting was updated after the attendee sent his response."*, which is not true. I can't find the appointment in my calendar, and the responses are not being tallied. When I open the msg file in Windows Explorer, I can copy it to my calendar, but then I just see my own name as the organizer, and not the responses from all attendees nor an option to update the invite.

How can I get the original sent out invite in my calendar so that I
(1) can see an overview of the responses from all attendees and
(2) can send an update to all attendees without sending a new appointment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you chose to save the appointment as a message file, you converted it from a `calendar format` to the `message format`. Outlook then recognized it as a message, not an appointment.

When you opened the message file and sent it, all you did was sent a message to all attendees (not an appointment). Therefore, since it was not a `calendar` item, Outlook treats it like a message and did not put it in the calendar or track responses.

You can not recover this sent item and responses. You have create a new appointment and send it as an appointment.